# Accessing resources attached to list items in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm accessing a list of calendar items on a SharePoint2013 site like so:

```
    public ListItemCollection GetListByTitle(string title)
    {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(_site);
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title);
        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery()); // Empty CamlQuery to return all items in list
        context.Load(listItems);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        return listItems;
    }
```

Then I'm passing that ListItemCollection to another method which will map some of the item's properties to a custom model

```
    public List<CustomModel>GetListOfCustomModel(ListItemCollection listItems)
    {
        List<CustomModel> customModelList = new List<CustomModel>();
        foreach(ListItem i in listItems)
        {
            FieldUserValue contact = (FieldUserValue)i.FieldValues["Contact"];
            string s = (string)(contact.LookupValue);
            string t = (string)i.FieldValues["Title"];
            DateTime start = (DateTime)i.FieldValues["EventDate"];
            // etc.
        }
    }
```

All of the "in-built" properties are easy to get, but I can't figure out how to access the resources the company has created and attached to these items.

E.g. each calendar item has a "Room" resource attached. I understand this is "meta data" but surely I should be able to access it somehow? It must be linked to the item I just don't know where to look. When I do a SharePoint list view for every column in the list I can see the "room" resource is generated as a link with reference to the resource.

Or am I going to end up viewing the text response from viewing my LISTALL page in a web request and parse the room out using good old fashioned string manipulation?!

Answer (score 0):

I'd been looking at this for a couple of days, and I found a piece of code that translates a `ListItemCollection` to a `DataTable`

This code handled `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue`, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]` but when I was looking at my Excel output I saw a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[]`

Debugged the code again and drilled down into this instance of a `FieldLookupValue[]` called `Facilities` which, lo and behold, has the room and all other "Resources" in there.

**SHORT ANSWER: Don't look for resources, look for FACILITIES**

Here's some code I lifted from another answer site that cycles through `ListItemCollection` and transposes info to a `DataTable` but amended to show `Id` as well as `value` for FieldUserValue arrays and, more importantly, do the same for `FieldLookupValue` arrays:

```
    public DataTable GetDataTableFromListItemCollection(ListItemCollection listItems)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var field in listItems[0].FieldValues.Keys)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(field);
        }

        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            foreach (var obj in item.FieldValues)
            {
                if (obj.Value != null)
                {
                    string key = obj.Key;
                    string type = obj.Value.GetType().FullName;

                    if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue")
                    {
                        dr[obj.Key] = ((FieldLookupValue)obj.Value).LookupValue;
                    }
                    else if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue")
                    {
                        dr[obj.Key] = ((FieldUserValue)obj.Value).LookupValue;
                    }
                    else if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]")
                    {
                        FieldUserValue[] multValue = (FieldUserValue[])obj.Value;
                        foreach (FieldUserValue fieldUserValue in multValue)
                        {
                            dr[obj.Key] += "&" + fieldUserValue.LookupId + "=" + fieldUserValue.LookupValue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (type == "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[]")
                    {
                        FieldLookupValue[] multValue = (FieldLookupValue[])obj.Value;
                        foreach (FieldLookupValue fieldLookupValue in multValue)
                        {
                            dr[obj.Key] += "&" + fieldLookupValue.LookupId + "=" + fieldLookupValue.LookupValue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (type == "System.DateTime")
                    {
                        if (obj.Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                        {
                            var date = obj.Value.ToString().Split(' ');
                            if (date[0].Length > 0)
                            {
                                dr[obj.Key] = date[0];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[obj.Key] = obj.Value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dr[obj.Key] = null;
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bf89ee1-50a1-4c21-9ef9-51bd4d2ae155/convert-listitemcollection-to-datatable-without-looping-through-all-list-items-using-csom?forum=SP2016